# Xcode 4: multiple workspaces open with same project?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, workspace

In reference to [Problems adding Projects to Workspace in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908041/problems-adding-projects-to-workspace-in-xcode-4), has anyone found a way of including the same project in several workspaces and having them open in Xcode 4 simultaneously?

For example, I have a project which builds a static library. I want to include that project in a workspace with a Mac app project, and in a workspace with an iOS app project.

Comment: Shockingly, this is still an issue in Xcode 8.2.1. I really liked sharing code in workspaces but this makes it impossible to maintain, so I had to revert to using git submodules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known limitation of the current Xcode 4 that it cannot reference the same project several times simultaneously in different workspaces. This has been reported, and Apple knows about it. However, it is not clear whether this is going to be fixed. The only way to increase the likelihood of Apple fixing it is for you to file a bug report.

One way to work around the limitation is to work as if Xcode couldn't open more than one workspace at a time. So for each of your workflow scenario, you simply create one workspace that contains all the projects you might be lead to work on in this scenario.

This leads to unnecessary workspace multiplication, but after all, this is not a big deal.

More critically, that's yet another case where Xcode 4 works hard to prevent the user from adopting a multi-window work style. I encourage you to file a bug report for this too, as feedback from WWDC indicates that Apple didn't find complaints about that loud enough to fix it.

Comment: Bug report submitted :) I really hope this is fixed soon. Even having a project reference is enough to not be able to open the referenced project!